# How to fix Guru meditation error on ESP32cam?

Tags: embedded, esp32, arduino-esp32

This is my code:

```
/*********
  Rui Santos
  Complete project details at https://RandomNerdTutorials.com/esp32-websocket-server-arduino/
  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
  copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*********/

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid = "chulaf";
const char* password = "2807975ev";

bool ledState = false;
unsigned long startTime;
const int IDLE = 0;
const int SOAP = 1;
const int WATER = 2;
const int DRYING = 3;
int currentState = IDLE;
const int ledPin1 = 2;      // GPIO 2 for Status LED 1
const int ledPin2 = 4;      // GPIO 4 for Status LED 2
const int ledPin3 = 12;     // GPIO 12 for Status LED 3
const int ledPin4 = 13;     // GPIO 13 for Status LED 4
const int dcMotorPin1 = 14; // GPIO 14 for DC Motor 1
const int dcMotorPin2 = 15; // GPIO 15 for DC Motor 2
const int fanPin = 16;      // GPIO 16 for Fan


// Create AsyncWebServer object on port 80
AsyncWebServer server(80);
AsyncWebSocket ws("/ws");

String receivedPythonValue = "No value received yet"; // Store received value here
String handSizeCategory = "Unknown"; // Default category

const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!-- Rest of the code remains the same -->

<style>
  body {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #0F0;
    font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
    text-align: center;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  #pythonValue {
    color: #00F;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  #handSize {
    color: #F00;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  /* Custom retro styling */
  span.retro {
    background-color: #0F0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  }
<style>
  body {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #0F0;
    font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
    text-align: center;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  #pythonValue {
    color: #00F;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  #handSize {
    color: #F00;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  #currentState {
    color: #0FF;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  /* Custom retro styling */
  span.retro {
    background-color: #0F0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  }
</style>

<h2>Hand area calculator</h2>
<p>Mean area of the hand: <span id="pythonValue" class="retro">%PYTHON_VALUE%</span></p>
<p>Hand Size Category: <span id="handSize" class="retro">%HAND_SIZE%</span></p>
<p>Current State: <span id="currentState" class="retro">%CURRENT_STATE%</span></p>

<!-- Add the following script to periodically update the value -->
<script>
  // Function to fetch the latest values and update the interface
  function updateValues() {
    fetch('/get-python-value')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(value => {
        document.getElementById('pythonValue').textContent = value;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching Python value:', error);
      });

    fetch('/get-hand-size')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(category => {
        document.getElementById('handSize').textContent = category;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching Hand Size:', error);
      });

    fetch('/get-current-state')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(state => {
        document.getElementById('currentState').textContent = state;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching Current State:', error);
      });
  }

  // Update the values every 2 seconds
  setInterval(updateValues, 2000);

  // Initial update
  updateValues();
</script>

<!-- Rest of the code remains the same -->
)rawliteral";

void notifyClients() {
  ws.textAll(String(ledState));
}

void handleWebSocketMessage(void *arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len) {
  AwsFrameInfo *info = (AwsFrameInfo*)arg;
  if (info->final && info->index == 0 && info->len == len && info->opcode == WS_TEXT) {
    data[len] = 0;
    if (strcmp((char*)data, "toggle") == 0) {
      ledState = !ledState;
      notifyClients();
    } else {
      receivedPythonValue = (char*)data; // Store the received value
      notifyClients();

      // Print the received Python value to the Serial Monitor
      Serial.print("Received Python value: ");
      Serial.println(receivedPythonValue);

      // Convert the received value to a numeric value (assuming it's a number)
     // Convert the received value to a numeric value (assuming it's a number)
      float handSize = receivedPythonValue.toFloat();

      // Categorize the hand size into small, medium, or large
      if (handSize >= 3000 && handSize < 5500) {
        handSizeCategory = "Small";
      } else if (handSize >= 5500 && handSize < 8500) {
        handSizeCategory = "Medium";
      } else {
        handSizeCategory = "Large";
      }

      // Print the hand size category
      Serial.print("Hand Size Category: ");
      Serial.println(handSizeCategory);
    }
  }
}

void onEvent(AsyncWebSocket *server, AsyncWebSocketClient *client, AwsEventType type,
             void *arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len) {
  switch (type) {
    case WS_EVT_CONNECT:
      Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u connected from %s\n", client->id(), client->remoteIP().toString().c_str());
      break;
    case WS_EVT_DISCONNECT:
      Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u disconnected\n", client->id());
      break;
    case WS_EVT_DATA:
      handleWebSocketMessage(arg, data, len);
      break;
    case WS_EVT_PONG:
    case WS_EVT_ERROR:
      break;
  }
}

void initWebSocket() {
  ws.onEvent(onEvent);
  server.addHandler(&ws);
}

String processor(const String& var){
  if(var == "STATE"){
    if (ledState){
      return "ON";
    }
    else{
      return "OFF";
    }
  } else if (var == "PYTHON_VALUE") {
    return receivedPythonValue; // Return the received value
  } else if (var == "HAND_SIZE") {
    return handSizeCategory; // Return the hand size category
  }
  return String();
}

void setup(){
  // Serial port for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(115200);

pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);   // Status LED 1
pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);   // Status LED 2
pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);   // Status LED 3
pinMode(ledPin4, OUTPUT);   // Status LED 4
pinMode(dcMotorPin1, OUTPUT);  // DC Motor 1
pinMode(dcMotorPin2, OUTPUT);  // DC Motor 2
pinMode(fanPin, OUTPUT);      // Fan
  
  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  // Print ESP Local IP Address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  initWebSocket();

  // Route for root / web page
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html, processor);
  });

  // Add the new route to fetch the Python value
  server.on("/get-python-value", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(200, "text/plain", receivedPythonValue);
  });

  // Add the new route to fetch the Hand Size category
  server.on("/get-hand-size", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(200, "text/plain", handSizeCategory);
  });

  // Start server
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  ws.cleanupClients();

  switch (currentState) {
    case IDLE:
      // Check if hand size category is assigned
      if (handSizeCategory != "Unknown") {
        currentState = SOAP;
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH); // Turn on Status LED 2
        startTime = millis();
      } else {
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW); // Turn off Status LED 2
        digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW); // Turn off Status LED 3
        digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW); // Turn off Status LED 4
      }
      break;

    case SOAP:
      // Perform actions for small hand size
      if ((millis() - startTime >= 500) && (millis() - startTime <= 7000)) {
        // Turn on DC Motor 1 for 7 seconds
        digitalWrite(dcMotorPin1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH); // Turn on Status LED 2
      } else {
        digitalWrite(dcMotorPin1, LOW); // Turn off DC Motor 1
        digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);     // Turn off Status LED 2
        currentState = WATER;
        digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH); // Turn on Status LED 3
        startTime = millis();
      }
      break;

    case WATER:
      // Perform actions for small hand size
      if ((millis() - startTime >= 500) && (millis() - startTime <= 10000)) {
        // Turn on DC Motor 2 for 10 seconds
        digitalWrite(dcMotorPin2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH); // Turn on Status LED 3
      } else {
        digitalWrite(dcMotorPin2, LOW); // Turn off DC Motor 2
        digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);     // Turn off Status LED 3
        currentState = DRYING;
        digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH); // Turn on Status LED 4
        startTime = millis();
      }
      break;

    case DRYING:
      // Perform actions for small hand size
      if ((millis() - startTime >= 500) && (millis() - startTime <= 15000)) {
        // Turn on Fan for 15 seconds
        digitalWrite(fanPin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH); // Turn on Status LED 4
      } else {
        digitalWrite(fanPin, LOW); // Turn off Fan
        digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW); // Turn off Status LED 4
        currentState = IDLE;
        handSizeCategory = "Unknown"; // Set hand size category to "Unknown" when the drying is done
        startTime = millis();
      }
      break;
  }

  // Add any other logic or actions you want to perform here

  delay(1000); // Add a delay to avoid rapid changes (adjust as needed)
}
```

and I get this error:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x4008dd18  PS      : 0x00060930  A0      : 0x800e0b71  A1      : 0x3ffca480  
A2      : 0xffffffff  A3      : 0xffffffff  A4      : 0xffffffff  A5      : 0x00060923  
A6      : 0x00060923  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x00000001  A9      : 0x00000004  
A10     : 0x00060923  A11     : 0x3ffc3c30  A12     : 0x3ffc3871  A13     : 0x00000004  
A14     : 0x007bf558  A15     : 0x003fffff  SAR     : 0x00000017  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x0000003f  LBEG    : 0x4008adf5  LEND    : 0x4008ae05  LCOUNT  : 0xfffffffa  


Backtrace: 0x4008dd15:0x3ffca480 0x400e0b6e:0x3ffca4c0 0x400e13fd:0x3ffca510 0x400de51c:0x3ffca540 0x400dcb05:0x3ffca560 0x400dcf93:0x3ffca580 0x400dd081:0x3ffca5a0 0x400d2f8e:0x3ffca5c0 0x400dea66:0x3ffca610




ELF file SHA256: bd833875e4d83b6e
```

what's interesting is that when I changed my pin numbers to some of these written here: https://github.com/donny681/ESP32_CAMERA_QR?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000023.17.78847e59f5HadU

as such:

```
const int ledPin1 = 5;      // GPIO 2 for Status LED 1
const int ledPin2 = 18;      // GPIO 4 for Status LED 2
const int ledPin3 = 19;     // GPIO 12 for Status LED 3
const int ledPin4 = 21;     // GPIO 13 for Status LED 4
const int dcMotorPin1 = 34; // GPIO 14 for DC Motor 1
const int dcMotorPin2 = 35; // GPIO 15 for DC Motor 2
const int fanPin = 36;      // GPIO 16 for Fan
```

There is no error message of this sort, but another:

```
E (33605) gpio: gpio_set_level(226): GPIO output gpio_num error
E (34605) gpio: gpio_set_level(226): GPIO output gpio_num error
E (35605) gpio: gpio_set_level(226): GPIO output gpio_num error
E (36605) gpio: gpio_set_level(226): GPIO output gpio_num error
E (37605) gpio: gpio_set_level(226): GPIO output gpio_num error
E (38605) gpio: gpio_set_level(226): GPIO output gpio_num error
E (39605) gpio: gpio_set_level(226): GPIO output gpio_num error
E (40605) gpio: gpio_set_level(226): GPIO output gpio_num error
E (41605) gpio: gpio_set_level(226): GPIO output gpio_num error
```

What should I do?

I have tried everything, i don't know which pin numbers to use anymore

Comment: Download and install [ESP Exception Decoder](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) on your Arduino IDE to decode the exception, find out which line cause it.

Comment: You need to know which camera module you are using and its pin map, you can't switch to AI-Thinker's camera module (as per your link) and expecting it has the same pin map as the first sketch.